# Javascript render jpeg binary data from variable

Tags: png, jpeg, javascript

How to render JPEG/PNG file data contained in Javascript variable? Is it possible ? What javascript libraries needed ? Browser in use is FF / IE.

Thanks

Comment: How could a JPEG/PNG image be contained in a javascript variable? Is it Base64 encoded?

Comment: Not Base64 Encoded, it's in binary format.

Comment: I get the binary data format from Flash Player in the page, transferred via ExternalInterface.

Comment: Please note that the Data schema may cause some issues with IE6+. In Particular you will have a mixed content warning if using HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers support [inline images](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/). So you could convert the binary data to a [base64 encoded string](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) and then append it to the DOM:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7';
img.width = '16';
img.height = '14';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```